# Two exercises by Robinson on supersolvable groups seem to contradict.

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, solvable-groups

This is concerning (part of) **Exercise 5.4.5** and **Exercise 5.4.6** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*.

I have done the first one; the second might take me a while.

### The Details:

The dihedral group is given by the presentation

$$D_{2n}\cong \langle r,s\mid r^n, s^2, srs=r^{-1}\rangle.$$

On page 150, paraphrased,

> A group $G$ is *supersolvable* if it has a series of normal subgroups
>
> $$1=G_0\unlhd G_1\unlhd \dots\unlhd  G_n=G$$
>
> all of whose factors $G_{i+1}/G_i$ are cyclic.

On page 157, we have the two exercises: part of

> **Exercise 5.4.5**: The class of supersolvable groups is closed with respect to [. . .] finite direct products

. . . and . . .

> **Exercise 5.4.6:** The product of two normal supersolvable subgroups need not be supersolvable. [*Hint:* Let $X$ be the subgroup of $GL(2,3)$ generated by
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
>
> thus $X\cong D_8$. Let $X$ act in the natural way on $A=\Bbb Z_3\oplus\Bbb Z_3$ and write $G=X\ltimes A$. Show that $G$ is not supersolvable. Let $L$ and $M$ be distinct Klein $4$-subgroups of $X$ and consider $H=LA$ and $K=MA$.]

### The Question:

> How does **Exercise 5.4.5** not contradict **Exercise 5.4.6**?

### Thoughts:

In **Exercise 5.4.6**, does Robinson mean the *subgroup* product

$$ST=\{ st\in C\mid s\in S, t\in T\}$$

for subgroups $S, T$ of a group $C$? I think so.

If not, then why does it not contradict **Exercise 5.4.5**?

A solution to (this part of) **Exercise 5.4.5** can be found here:

- [How is the direct product of two supersolvable groups again supersolvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2070877/104041)

---

Please help :)

Comment: The exercise says: "The product of two normal supersolvable subgroups ...", and then you ask "does Robinson mean the subgroup product?". Isn't that exactly what it says?

Comment: I suppose so, @DerekHolt; it just wasn't clear to me at first. Thank you.

Comment: There is no ambiguity about the product of two subgroups of the same group. But occasionally people talk about the product of two groups, where there is no connection between the two groups. That is very unclear. Direct product? Free product?

Comment: Why do you think they contradict each other? 5.4.6 says that if $G$ is a group, and $H,K$ are both normal in $G$ and each is supersolvable, it need not be the case that $HK$ (which is a subgroup of $G$) is supersolvable (I would also call this "the product of the subgroups", but perhaps that's just me). 5.4.4 says that if $G_1,\ldots,G_n$ are each supersolvable, then $G_1\times\cdots\times G_n$ is supersolvable. Note that for $H$ and $K$ as above, $HK$ need not be isomorphic to a direct product.

Comment: Thank you. My issue was I thought that perhaps some *internal* direct product was intended, @ArturoMagidin. I suppose this was a stupid question . . .

Comment: @Shaun: No worries. We all do that kind of thing from time to time: can't *possibly* be that, I must be missing something.... ooops, not, it really is that. :-)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/459816/104041) is an example of $ST$ not being supersolvable for normal, supersolvable subgroups $S$ and $T$.